# Slack Bot API Remove the Post To Permission

Tags: slack, slack-api

How do I remove the Post To Permission when user installs my bot?

This is the Post To that I meant:
[image]

This is my slack button `href`:

```
<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?&client_id={{$client_id}}&scope=incoming-webhook,bot,commands,channels:read,users:read,users:read.email,channels:write,chat:write:bot,users.profile:read"><span>Add to Slack</span></a>
```

This is also my permission scope:

[image]

[image]

Is there something that I need to remove there in order for the "Post To" to be removed everytime a team installs my bot?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's the **incoming-webhook** scope which is asking you for a default channel to post messages.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to remove {incoming-webhooks}. You would need to turn off 'incoming-webhook' under your apps Incoming Webhooks.